# Match characters based on a text pattern "image"

Tags: java, ascii, pattern-matching, design-patterns

What would be a good way to approach matching a String pattern of X's to any uppercase letter in the alphabet, A-Z, given a master pattern. I'm looking for either a code example (in Java) or just a general algorithm idea.

For example, I'm given the "master pattern" for 'T' of:

```
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X            
        X  X
```

...and all of the following patterns must be determined to be T's based on the master pattern.

```
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
     X  X  X         
        X            
        X            
        X            
        X            
        X            
        X            
        X            
        X            
        X
```

or

```
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X            
     X  X
```

or

```
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X         
            X  X
```

The algorithm would have to be generic enough to work for all letters; T is just an example.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem, and not specific in any way to Java.  You probably need to read up on *optical character recognition*.

Comment: Nothing to do with OCR. OCR is parsing characters from an Image. These are already characters (that form characters).  I need the final algorithm to be in Java, as that's my Dev environment

Comment: This is still OCR.  You're doing pattern recognition/classification, based on a bitmap.  That bitmap isn't a photo or a scanned-in image, but the principles are identical.

Comment: On the contrary, this is exactly OCR.  More generally, OCR is the extraction of textual data from *any* (traditionally two-dimensional) signal.  What you describe (files consisting of graphical arrangements of characters) is quite akin to a binary "image".

Comment: OK, I will go down the road of OCR'ing these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into http://jocr.sourceforge.net/, which is a free OCR library.  It's a C library, so using it directly is probably not an option for you.  If nothing else, you can at least dig through the source.

You may also want to take a peak at http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/38736, which is a pure JavaScript implementation of a neural-net based OCR algorithm.

As has been mentioned in the comments already this is by no means a trivial problem to solve well, but you might be able to get by on a naive neural net that suits your data.